# xpath not returning or scraping the value

Tags: xpath

In the code below the coupon value is always blank whether it is present or not.

I am trying to extract the code and title only when the coupon is present but it won't work - it just returns a blank page.

```php
$url="http://www.grabon.in/amazon-coupons/";
$storename="AMAZON";

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1');
$html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$mydoc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(empty($html)) die("EMPTY HTML");
    //echo ($html);
    $mydoc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $my_xpath = new DOMXPath($mydoc);


    $nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//div[@id="category_coupons"]' );

    foreach( $nodes as $node )
    {


        $code=$my_xpath->query( 'article[@class="sm-coupon"]/div[@class="smc-actions"]/div[@class="smc-actions-r"]/div[@class="sm-code"]/span', $node );
        if ($code->length>0){

           $coupon = $code->item(0)->nodeValue ;
           $title  = $my_xpath->query( 'article[@class="sm-coupon"]/div[@class="smc-info"]/h3', $node )->item(0)->nodeValue;


        echo $storename.",".$title.",".$coupon."<br>";

        }


     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with syntax you use, but I guess that you want to use found `nodes` to find child articles... If so, you need to use `XPath` like

```
./article[@class="sm-coupon"]/div[@class="smc-info"]/h3
```

as `./` points on parent `node` element while using just

```
article[@class="sm-coupon"]...
```

without specifying `./` means that you need `root` `article` element

**Update**

If you want to get title of only those `articles` that contains code, use below `XPath`:

```
//div[@class="smc-actions" and ./descendant::div[@class="sm-code"]/span[text()]]/preceding-sibling::div[@class="smc-info"]/h3
```

`XPath` for codes is simply

```
//div[@class="sm-code"]/span[text()]
```

**Final code**:

```
$titles = $my_xpath->query( '//div[@class="smc-actions" and./descendant::div[@class="sm-code"]/span[text()]]/preceding-sibling::div[@class="smc-info"]/h3' );
$coupons = $my_xpath->query( '//div[@class="sm-code"]/span[text()]' );
foreach(range(0, $titles->length-1) as $index)
{ echo $storename.",".$titles->item($index)->nodeValue.",".$coupons->item($index)->nodeValue."<br>"; }
```

Comment: i changed the line to '$title  = $my_xpath->query( './article[@class="sm-coupon"]/div[@class="smc-info"]/h3', $node )->item(0)->nodeValue;' but still its blank ...feel free to change the syntax i know thee are multiple ways to get the results

Comment: You want to get title like `"Samsung Mobiles: Upto Rs 2000 OFF"` or `"Upto 30% OFF Best Selling Laptops"` + coupon like `"STOPOFF8"` or `"WEST7OFF"`, right?

Comment: Ok. Can you check updated answer and let me know if you get desired output?

Comment: i m getting error Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string on the line echo $storename.",".$title.",".$coupon."<br>";....could u possibly correct the lines in my code itself and and repost the whole code...maybe i am making a mistake somewhere

Comment: ok it worked but its pulling out only 1 data not all the coupons and their titles...

Comment: As I said I'm not familiar with the language/syntax you use in your code(( I just can suggest you correct `XPath` expression to match required elements (you specified only `XPath` tag in your ticket)... Do you get single pair title+code instead of 4 pairs (I found 4 on first page)?

Comment: I suppose you got only first matched pair of elements... Did you try to get two lists of elements and iterate through it with loop?

Comment: how do i do tht? ow do i get it to list all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137991/discussion-between-andersson-and-sonia-k).